# bindRows is not a function

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to bind data from NWGW to an existing javascript table for Input value help using `getTable().bindRows`.

Development tool is WebIDE, All connections are checked. All oData services are OK and providing Live Data, metadata OK.

But I keep getting

> Uncaught TypeError: oValueHelpDialog.getTable(...).bindRows is not a
>   function.

This only happens if the app is running on a small screen device (phone or if I choose phone layout in Chrome Dev Tool).

I don't know if it is because it can get the odata to bind to the table? Does phone handle UI5 differently?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

-------Update-------

Thank to a nice guy in Answer.SAP. Here is the [sample project](http://embed.plnkr.co/w5xFqO/)

Step to reproduce the error:

- Import the project to Web IDE
- Execute the index.html
- Open Chrome Dev Tool
- Choose device: iPhone 6/7/8 or whatever phone
- Refresh (F5) the app
- Click on Value Help Dialog again > lead to a blank table

-------Update END-------

**Fragment view**

```
    var oValueHelpDialog = new sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog({
        title : oController.getStrTextSite(),
        supportMultiselect : false,
        supportRanges : false,
        supportRangesOnly : false,
        key : oController.getStrWERKS(),
        descriptionKey : oController.getStrNAME1(),
        ok: function(oControlEvent) {
            oController.setDefaultSiteFromHelp(oControlEvent);
            oValueHelpDialog.close();
        },
        cancel: function(oControlEvent) {
            oValueHelpDialog.close();
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            oValueHelpDialog.destroy();
        }
    });     
    ...     
    return oValueHelpDialog;
}
```

**Controller**

```
onValueHelpForDefaultSite : function(oEvent) {          
        var oValueHelpDialog = this.getFragmentForValueHelp();
        oValueHelpDialog.open();            
        ...         
        oValueHelpDialog.getTable().bindRows(
            this.getEntitySet(
                "ODATA_10_DEFAULT_SITE_SET",
                "ODATA_10"
            )
        );
    }
```

Comment: which table are you using? ".bindRows" is not a function in sap.m.table. However, There are other ways to achieve what trying.

Comment: Too much code --- trim this down to a [mcve] please.

Comment: @Robert, I trim down a bit

Comment: @NandanChaturvedi  I'm not using sap.m.table in index.html. But it's not the cause I think. Because the issue only happens on small screen devices.

Comment: You said _existing javascript table_, is this a UI5 control?

Comment: Check the instance of `oValueHelpDialog` ie  `if(oValueHelpDialog) { oValueHelpDialog.getTable().bindRows( ..`

Comment: @inizio yes, it's a `sap.ui.comp.valuehelpdialog.ValueHelpDialog`

If I add `if(oValueHelpDialog) { oValueHelpDialog.getTable().bindRows( ..)} ` then I can see `oValueHelpDialog` is instantiated

Comment: Have you tried a `console.log(oValueHelpDialog.getTable())` to see what it actually returns?

Comment: @TiiJ7 I tried, it can return object, not `undefined`

Comment: @TiiJ7, this is console.log(oValueHelpDialog.getTable()) [link](https://answers.sap.com/storage/temp/178276-consolelog.png)

Comment: I added a sample project to the question. I hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in mobile, function `bindRows()` does not exist so we have to replace it with function `bindItems()`